# How do you create editable content in a ConstantContact custom template?

Tags: email, constantcontact

I'm forced to use ConstantContact as a development platform for email marketing, and it offers some custom XHTML tags like `<Property>` and `<Article>`, and the documentation over at http://constantcontact.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/constantcontact.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=2215 seems to assume that adding such a tag into your custom XHTML template will simply allow the property to be editable in the "control panel" area rather than hidden deep in the HTML code.

My client is not experienced with hunting through code to find the area that needs to be edited, so I'd like to make it easy on them and allow the text to be editable in a textarea right from the control panel. This is possible with the "Greeting" property. Can I create custom properties in ConstantContact much like the default `<Greeting />`, which can be edited right from the wizard?

Comment: Does the Constant Contact API not allow for variables to be passed through to the content of the email?

Comment: It seems to, but I'm not sure how to actually set those variables...

Answer (score 3):

Since I didn't see a rated answer, I figured I'd add one.

Just to clarify, Constant Contact is a crap service that skates by on name recognition and clients too ignorant to know there are better options. (No offense to your client...)

Now, to answer your question, there is no way currently (4.13.13) for you (or any developer outside of the Constant Contact fortress) to create a custom template that can be used within their WYSIWYG editor.

The only way to have a truly custom design converted into an editable template is to send Constant Contact your art files and pay them $600 to create it for you.
http://www.constantcontact.com/services/email-marketing/index.jsp#template-creation

So I feel your pain, as I've been in this exact situation.

Comment: Upvote solely based on your opinion of Constant Contact. Well said sir.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to this as I just faced a similar problem.  After spending 6 hours building an HTML and testing it via MailChimp - I prefer it 100% - I had to then port it across to Constant Contact (CC).  They have an advanced editor but as the persons above mentioned, you cannot add editable areas - it looks like you need to use XHTML for that...?

However that all said, my work around was to take a template they provide that looks as close as possible to my design and then manipulate it as you get to edit the HTML for those areas.  I have to say, I was able to get my email to almost 100% the same - not being able to edit the disclaimer stuff at the bottom was a pain.

The only reason I couldn't get them to move to MailChimp - a 100% superior bit of kit - was because their CRM system is tied up with CC.